# Metro App Touch Gesture equivalent to Keyboard Enter

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Is there an equivalent **Touch gesture** for a **Keyboard Enter key** in a Windows 8 Metro App, that can be detected in the `KeyDown` or similar event for a `TextBox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the docs for [designing for touch interaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465415.aspx), which includes the Microsoft Touch language.

Apps should endeavor to follow the Microsoft Touch language as much as possible.

You should not need a touch gesture specifically for the equivalent of the Enter key because if the user is using a keyboard (for example, on a laptop), they would have the Enter key available physically. If a keyboard is not present (for example on  Surface or other tablet), then tapping inside the textbox would bring up the soft input panel, which likewise includes the Enter key. You can find [more information on keyboard and SIP support here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700405.aspx).

Hope that helps.

For more information on Windows Store app development, register for [App Builder](http://bit.ly/gd30tolaunch).

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at it wrong. So basically my code stays the same, because when the user has to input from the soft panel, all relevant events with the keys that were input are triggered same as with physical keyboard.